# change the used equality operator for a "case" block (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, comparison, switch-statement

I want to have a code like:

```
x = Date

case x
when Date
  puts "Date"
when String
  puts "String"
else
  puts "Unknown"
end
```

I know that `x == Date` is true, but `x === Date` is false. So I get "Unknown" when I expect "Date".

Any way to change the used operator/function for the block above so I can get the expected result?

Comment: What is relevant here is the fact that `Date === x` is `false`. The fact that `x === Date` is `false` is irrelevant. Misleadingly, `===` is not commutative.

Comment: You usually use `case` for instances, but here `x` is a class. Of course it's legit, but it's not usual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x = Date

case x.name
when "Date"
  puts "Date"
when "String"
  puts "String"
else
  puts "Unknown"
end
```

Comment: from last 10 mins, i was trying to remember this,but failed. now after seeing your one,got my life back. :)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, if you must have comparison other than `===` in a case statement, you have to use the more verbose syntax of `case`:

```
x = Date

case
when x == Date
  puts "Date"
when x == String
  puts "String"
else
  puts "Unknown"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is:

```
class ComparableClass
  attr_accessor :klass

  def initialize(klass)
    @klass = klass
  end
end

class Class
  alias_method :'old_triple_equals', :'==='

  def ===(other)
    if other.is_a? ComparableClass
      self == other.klass
    else
      old_triple_equals(other)
    end
  end
end

klass = Date

case ComparableClass.new(klass)
when Date
  puts 'Its a date'
when String
  puts 'Its a string'
else
  puts 'Its something else'
end

#=> Its a date
```

Comment: +1 for "going there" and actually altering behaviour of `===`. Sledgehammer vs nut for this `case` statement I feel, but you never know when it could turn out useful to have this control.